# Java regex pattern match for []

Tags: java, regex

I have a string output which I need to match and I am using a `regex`

```
String schemaName = "Amazon";
String test = "{\"data\": [], \"name\": \"Amazon\", \"title\": \"StoreDataConfig\"}";
String output= method("\\[\\]",schemaName);
Matcher n = Pattern.compile(output).matcher(test);
boolean available = n.find();
System.out.println(available);
```

I wanted to validate the same and passing the regex to a method as mentioned

```
private static String method(String data, String schemaName) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(data);
    return ("{\"data\": "  + data  + ", \"name\": " + "\"" + schemaName + "\"" + ", \"title\": \"StoreDataConfig\"}");
}
```

But I am always getting `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition`.

Can you let me know what is the mistake?

If I don't use a method for `[]` and just giving it directly, I am not getting an error

Comment: You should not use a regex at all here, parse the json and handle the resulting array / map / business object.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing this:

1. Take a valid regex for matching `[]`.
2. Embed the regex in some JSON
3. Attempt to compile the JSON-with-an-embedded-regex as if the whole lot was a valid regex.

That fails ... because the JSON-with-an-embedded-regex is not a valid regex.

For a start, the `{` character is a regex meta character.

---

But the real puzzle is .... what are you actually trying to do here?

If you simply want a regex that matches a literal string then this will do it.

```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(someLiteralString)).
```

And you could build a regex out of sub-regexes and literal strings by using Pattern.quote to escape the literal parts and then concatenating.

---

If what you are ultimately trying to do here is to extract information from a JSON string using pattern matching / regexes, then ... don't.  The better approach is to use a proper JSON parser, and extract the information you need from the JSON object tree.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to escape `{}` characters like this `"\\{"`